# Log duration mismatch

Tags: postgresql

Based on my PostgreSQL settings, I would only expect statements to get printed if they ran for more than 50ms. However, according to the duration logs, these statements are running for significantly less time.

In the one example I looked at, I saw 3 different duration logs for the same transactions (I'm guessing they correspond to the Parse, Bind, and Execute steps), which combine to a total of ~35ms. However, the SQL query still got printed out anyway.

Why is there is mismatch here? Am I misreading the logs in some way?

Postgresql documentation:

```
log_min_duration_statement (integer)
Causes the duration of each completed statement to be logged if the statement ran for at least the specified number of milliseconds. Setting this to zero prints all statement durations. Minus-one (the default) disables logging statement durations. For example, if you set it to 250ms then all SQL statements that run 250ms or longer will be logged. Enabling this parameter can be helpful in tracking down unoptimized queries in your applications. Only superusers can change this setting.

log_duration (boolean)
Causes the duration of every completed statement to be logged. The default is off. Only superusers can change this setting.
For clients using extended query protocol, durations of the Parse, Bind, and Execute steps are logged independently.
```

My settings:

```
log_min_duration_statement 50
log_statement all
log_duration 1
```

Log for one transaction (looking for all lines nearby that have the 8603 id. I do see both 8603 and 47611 IDs being reused multiple times over a long time period. Is this causing some form of duration-value-collision?)

```
2015-12-08 04:30:19 UTC:ec2-54-146-195-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com(47611):xxxx@xxxx:[8603]:LOG: duration: 4.637 ms
2015-12-08 04:30:19 UTC:ec2-54-146-195-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com(47611):xxxx@xxxx:[8603]:LOG: duration: 22.992 ms
2015-12-08 04:30:19 UTC:ec2-54-146-195-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com(47611):xxxx@xxxx:[8603]:LOG: execute <unnamed>: select * ...
2015-12-08 04:30:19 UTC:ec2-54-146-195-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com(47611):xxxx@xxxx:[8603]:DETAIL: parameters: ...
2015-12-08 04:30:19 UTC:ec2-54-146-195-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com(47611):xxxx@xxxx:[8603]:LOG: duration: 7.875 ms
```